# How do I get JSON.Stringify to parse variable correctly?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I can't figure this out :-( My Client is doing an ajax httppost and I need the following to be sent over:

```
  private doSaveQuery(queryName: string): void {

    const info = {};
    info['userName'] = 'admin';
    info['userQueryName'] = queryName;
    ...
```

When it gets stringified it turns it into this:

```
{"userName":"admin",
 "userQueryName":{"queryName":"MyName"}
}
```

Why does it take my variable name "queryName" and adds it as a key to my value?????

How do I get to this?

```
{"userName":"admin",
  "userQueryName":"MyName"
}
```

I know this is something simple so please forgive my ignorance :-)

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted would not do what you say it does.

Comment: You sure you didn't do `info['userQueryName'] = {queryName}` instead of `info['userQueryName'] = queryName`?

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger what value and type `queryName` actually has? Nevermind the type annotation, check the real value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are encoding the object it looks like `queryName` is actually an object that looks like `{queryName: 'MyName'}`.

To fix this you should make sure that `queryName` is just the string `MyName`.

```
info['userQueryName'] = 'MyName'
```

In order words, `queryName` is not what you think it is.

Example of your current implementation:

```js
const queryName = {queryName: "MyName"}
const info = {
  userName: "admin",
  userQueryName: queryName
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(info))
```

You should change `queryName` to just the string:

```js
const queryName = "MyName"
const info = {
  userName: "admin",
  userQueryName: queryName
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(info))
```

If you can't do then, then you could build info from the property:

```js
const queryName = {queryName: "MyName"}
const info = {
  userName: "admin",
  userQueryName: queryName.queryName
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(info))
```

Answer (score 1):

You specified as a type string, and typescript probably should've caught that you're not passing a string. Because if you do, it would do what you want.
But probably happens something like this.

```js
function getMyJSON(queryName) {
   const info = {};
    info['userName'] = 'admin';
    info['userQueryName'] = queryName;
  return info;
}

const a = {queryName:"name"};

console.log(JSON.stringify(getMyJSON(a)));
```